# PSS-Remoting problem while connecting to a connection broker to retrieve sessions

Tags: powershell, session, remoting

Tryin to be synthetic, I'm trying to connecting from a W7 operating system to a connection broker in order to retrieve all of the user's sessions with this simple function:

`Get-RDUsersession -connectionbroker 'xx' -collectionname 'xx'`

Since I discovered that it can't be done from W7 because the remotedesktop module can't be downloaded even after installed RSAT, some users advise me to use PSSRemoting commands in order to send command on a remote computer where surely the function works and thanks to this way run the entire script i've made on the local computer.

The problem, as you can see in the image attacched, is that it keeps me prompt out this error:

> A remote desktop services deployment does not exist on server.se

The same command works on W10 and i'm sure the RDS Deployment exist on that server. I've tried a lot of ways but i can't figure out why it doesn't works.
Someone can help me out ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're not really running your command using PowerShell Remoting (H: is not on the remote system as you can see in your screenshot).

Connect to the remote system using:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "yourRemoteMachine"
```

and the run your `Get-RDUsersession -connectionbroker "xx"` command.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Akq1.png

Comment: Ops yeah sorry i've uploaded the wrong screen shot. Above the right one.